# Cannot marshal a List to a file through Apache Camel route

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, activemq-classic, marshalling

I am trying to produce two files through marshaling from csv with the help of apache camel.
I trigger the production of the file sending an empty message through an active mq route which runs a method in a java class.
I create and fill up two Lists which I then send through two direct routes to produce the two files.
First route works fine creating a file from a List.
Second route doesn't create any file. It logs the below message and then recalls the method that trigered the production of the files.
Only difference between the two routes is the size of the List that gets send to the direct route which I log before sending the list to the route (segment: list2csvFullDataRest.size() : 11379).

Why does this happen? What is the restriction and from who? How can I make this work?

log file:

```
2014-07-23 16:42:55,305|INFO |SegmentNumbersJob         |.SegmentNumbersJob  144|325-1.2.1.SNAPSHOT|segment: list2csvFullDataRest.size() : 11379

[segmentNumberFullDat] [segmentNumberFullDat] [direct://segmentNumbersFullDataRest                                             ] [       245]
[segmentNumberFullDat] [marshal16         ] [marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat@3808692b]             ] [       245]
[segmentNumberTestRou] [segmentNumberTestRou] [amqNonXA://app.campaign.segmentNumbersJob?asyncConsumer=false&concurrentConsu] [     55861]
[segmentNumberTestRou] [to95              ] [bean:segmentNumbersJob?method=execute                                           ] [     55860]
        Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID:thodoris-pc-53142-1406126515417-1:1:1:1:1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://app.campaign.segmentNumbersJob, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:thodoris-pc-53142-1406126515417-1:1:1:1:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1406126516635, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null}

2014-07-23 16:42:56,629|INFO |SegmentNumbersJob         |.SegmentNumbersJob   66|325-1.2.1.SNAPSHOT|Generating segment reports...
```

route that triggers the method to produce the files:

```
from("amqNonXA:app.campaign.segmentNumbersJob?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=1&asyncConsumer=false&destination.consumer.prefetchSize=1&transacted=true")
.routeId("segmentNumberTestRoute")
.autoStartup(true)
.inOnly("bean:segmentNumbersJob?method=execute");
```

route that marshals the List like a csv and exports it as a file:

```
from("direct:segmentNumbersFullDataRest")
.autoStartup(true)
.marshal().csv()
.end()
```

code in the class segmentNumbersJob where the method execute is that sends the List to a direct route with the help of a ProducerTemplate

```
@EndpointInject
private ProducerTemplate segmentNumbersJobSender;
List<Map<String, Object>> list2csvFullDataRest = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

LOG.info("segment: list2csvFullDataRest.size() : " + list2csvFullDataRest.size());
// this is the code that doesn't execute properly even though a same line with a smaller List does!!!
segmentNumbersJobSender.sendBody("direct:segmentNumbersFullDataRest", list2csvFullDataRest);
```

Comment: Can you post fuller versions of your route definitions? It's not clear if you've got multiple consumers on your route or just multiple producers. The Direct component does not support multiple consumers.

Comment: There are no multiple consumers as far as I can tell. One class, one thread, is sending a List through a direct route with the help of a ProducerTemplate.

Comment: So where do you two routes come in? Do you have two routes defines the same way running at the same time?

Comment: There is an almost identical route that is called the same way as direct:segmentNumbersFullDataRest which is defined as direct:segmentNumbersData which runs and exports a file but with a much smaller List passed in.

Comment: Ok, something is screwed up with your routing but there's not enough code posted to reproduce the problem. You either need to post enough of your route and Java to someone can reproduce the issue or start changing things around. You've got one route which works and one that doesn't work. First try just running your failing route. That'll tell you if its a problem with the interaction between the routes or there's something wrong with the route itself. Second action depends on the result of the first test.